# Flask-MySQL - commands out of sync

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm having issues with reading data out of mysql with a cursor and displaying it over HTTP via flask. Everytime I run this code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, session, url_for, redirect, \
     render_template, abort, g, flash, _app_ctx_stack
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from contextlib import closing
from hashlib import md5
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
from werkzeug import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
import config

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = config.MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = config.MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = config.MYSQL_DATABASE_USER
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = config.MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = config.MYSQL_DATABASE_DB

mysql.init_app(app)

if 'SECRET_KEY' in os.environ:
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
else:
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

###
# Routing for your application.
###

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('init.sql') as f:
            db.cursor().execute(f.read())
        db.commit()


def connect_db():
    return mysql.connect()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get this result:

```
(venv)λ fh → λ git master* → python app.py                                              
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't ru
n this command now") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object a
t 0x10bc3ddd0>> ignored                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                      
  File "app.py", line 124, in <module>                                                  
    init_db()                                                                           
  File "app.py", line 38, in init_db                                                    
    db.commit()                                                                         
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this com
mand now")
```

Any ideas? I'm new to flask.

Comment: Flask is a web application framework. When I attempt to initialize the database once on application run, I hit a strange mysql error. Googling hasn't helped me. I added more code, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to start the app *before* trying to do your DB stuff, as you are accessing the DB through Flask. I'm not experienced with Flask, so I'm not sure how you can access the DB after starting the server, but I can look if you don't know. Basically,

```
init_db()
app.run(debug=True)
```

needs to be reversed to

```
app.run(debug=True)
init_db()
```

In some way.

Comment: This doesn't work. The db context never gets initialized. It's a hack.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I said you have to "do this in some way." `app.run()` blocks, but `init_db()` must be run *after* the Flask setup, which is done in `app.run()`.

Comment: I don't think you understand, init_db() never gets called, and if it did, it would erase the entire database.

Comment: Well, how do you close the program? Ctrl+C, I imagine? If so, the exception just by-passes the init_db() part.

Comment: Correct. The goal is to use init_db() properly at the beginning. To not use it all is the incorrect solution.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. What I was trying to say is, somehow your `init_db()` call must be inserted into `app.run()`.

Comment: No, it needs to be inserted before app.run() like how I have it.

Comment: In case you haven't figured this out yet, you have to have the app going before running `app.run()`. Try taking a look at what `app.run()` actually does, and recreate that.

Comment: app.run() initializes the web server. I want to initialize the database first before I initialize the web server. Does that make sense? (hence init_db() before app.run()). I'm not going to recreate Flask, this is a configuration issue.

Comment: If you really want to call stuff like that, my only answer is, it can't be done.